# Android : remove persistent permission for the Storage Access Framework

Tags: android

I add a persistent permission for the Storage Access Framework :

```
getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(treeUri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
```

but how to remove it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Call `releasePersistableUriPermission()` on `ContentResolver`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver#releasePersistableUriPermission(android.net.Uri,%20int)), using the same values as you did with your `takePersistableUriPermission()` call.